# How to bring your Google app scripts to Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I have scripts that I made with Google script editor. Basically what my scripts do is make and change google SpreadSheets, Slides, and Docs. It is logical that Google puts a limit on the amount of computing that you can do. The error that I get is this:

[Error in Apps Script executions Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNljJ.png)

My question is how can I bring my scripts to Google Cloud Platform and pay for the computing power? So that I can finish my work. I am not sure where to start in the Google Cloud Platform. Or can I use my own computer as computing power?

Any Help, tips, or tricks are welcome,  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Apps Scripts are already part of your default project in Google Cloud Platform, and it is GCP that manages your quota for services and API's that are being executed in those scripts.

Please check your codes, identify areas in which there are a lot of API executions, and try to optimize, for example, removing API calls within loops, etc. Here is a reference of quotas that are managed in GCP for Apps Script:

[Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#note1)

If the code is already optimized, then you can apply for increased quota here:

[Monitor API Quotas](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6301355)